# How to implement multiple views in single parent view in iPad?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an iOS application which runs on the iPad. So the iPad has a larger screen than iPhones so that it can include many views within a single `UIViewController` which makes the `UIViewController` code very bulky and design is messed up.

I've been using ContainerView for now. I use 'protocol delegate' to pass data from child view's view controller to container view's view controller and `NotificationCenter` to pass data from container view's view controller to child view's view controller. I would like to know other approaches to this.

Comment: Why you need other approach?? You can directly send data from container to child. But for reverse you need **delegate-protocol** or **NotificationCenter**. So now whats the issue you'r facing?

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48892520/6257435 It shows how to get a reference to the VC loaded into the container view.

Comment: @ dahiya_boy I want to know if there are other approaches.

Comment: In fact, you also can have an instance of each child in the parent. You can get the instance from prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?). And I think these are all the options for communication between parent and child.

Comment: [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH2-SW1) will tell you everything you need to know about how to properly utilize view controllers in your iOS application

Comment: @DonMag This is slightly better, I wouldn't have to use Notification center for each viewcontrollers of container views. Thanks