# Refreshing Child Controllers with Segmented Control

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have parent View Controller containing two Container Views and a segmented control that switches between the two views. Each Container View displays a tableView. The two child view controllers are called printingView and completedView.

A user can mark an item as complete and it is removed from the printingView tableView and displayed on the completedView tableView. The issue I have is refreshing the completedView tableView when the segmentedControl switches over to display that view. As of now, when item is removed from printingView, I need to navigate to another page and come back to PrintJobs ViewController in order to see the item appear in completedView.

As implemented, the two views are hidden and shown appropriately. Since the views are still active on the page, the child tableView does not update when the segmented controller is switched. How can I implement the child tableviews so that it reloads when the segmentedControl is invoked?

**Parent VC**

```swift
class PrintJobsVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var printingView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var completedView: UIView!

    var printer:PrinterDisplay? // passed from the VC before via segue

    @IBAction func toggleSegmentedController(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            // PrintingView
            setView(view: printingView, hidden: false)
            setView(view: completedView, hidden: true)

        case 1:
            // CompletedView
            setView(view: printingView, hidden: true)
            setView(view: completedView, hidden: false)

        default:
            print("hit default case of toggleSegmentedController")
            setView(view: printingView, hidden: false)
            setView(view: completedView, hidden: true)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "PrintingSegue", let nextVC = segue.destination as? IndividualPrintingVC {
            print("individualPrinting segue")
            nextVC.printer = printer
        } else if segue.identifier == "CompletedSegue", let nextVC = segue.destination as? IndividualCompletedVC {
            print("completedSegue")
            nextVC.printer = printer
        }
    }

    func setView(view: UIView, hidden: Bool) {
        UIView.transition(with: view, duration: 0.3, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
            view.isHidden = hidden
        })
    }

}
```

**Child PrintingVC (CompletedVC has the same layout)**

```
class PrintingVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var printer:PrinterDisplay?
    var printingArray:[PrintingDisplay] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        getCoreData() // retrieves from core data and stores in printingArray
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
    }
}

// tableview methods
extension PrintingVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    // set up how many rows are in the tableview
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return printingArray.count
    }
    
    // sets up a cell in the tableview
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PrintingCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! PrintingTableViewCell
        
        let item = printingArray[indexPath.row]
        // setup cell parameters

        return cell
    }
}

// mark the item as complete, remove from printingArray, modify Core Data
extension PrintingVC: PrintingTableViewCellDelegate {
    func markCompleted(row: Int, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = printingArray[row]
        // confirm that the user wants to complete print
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure?", message: "\(item.item) will be marked as completed. It can be found in the printer's individual page", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: {action in
            self.markCompletedCoreData(uid: item.uid)
            self.printingArray.remove(at: row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this question / answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48892520/6257435

Comment: @DonMag I've looked at the post and tried storing references to the child VCs when the segues are invoked. In the segmentedController I call their respective tableView.reloadData() in the main thread but still facing the same issue. The tableview is not updating when switching the segmented controller.

Comment: I assume each of your Child VCs are table view controllers? How are you managing their data? Are you using a "data manager" class? When the user marks an item "Completed" in the `printingView` table, are you removing it from `printingView` controller's data and adding it to `completedView` controllers data? And then calling `.reloadData` on the `completedView` controller?

Comment: The child VCs are UIContainerViews with a tableView embedded in them. They both have their respective classes (PrintingVC, CompletedVC) containing the tableview and array. So when an item is marked in PrintingVC, it is removed from the printing array tableview and it's boolean completed attribute is updated in core data. Since CompletedVC pulls from core data once the view loads, this item does not appear on the CompletedVC array and tableview until it is refreshed (parent view gets reloaded, fresh pull from core data). I've added the code snippets for the child VCs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this...

---

With your current approach, for each of your child VCs, you are loading your data from Core Data in `viewDidLoad()` into an array. You then use that array to populate the tables.

When you mark an item "Completed" in `PrintingVC`, you update Core Data, remove the element from the array, and remove the row from the table.

The problem is, that doesn't update the array in `CompletedVC`.

So, you would need to have `PrintingVC` tell `PrintJobsVC` that a record was changed (using either a closure or protocol / delegate pattern), and then `PrintJobsVC` would tell `CompletedVC` to update ***its*** array and reload its table.

That approach is rather "brute force" but would work.

---

A better approach could be to use a Fetched Results Controller and Managed Object Context to ***observe*** the change to Core Data and automatically update / refresh the table view.

You'll want to do some research (lots of tutorials out there) to learn how to do that.